# *ngSwitchCase not working for dynamically added ion-segment

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am unable to bind dynamic values to ngSwitchCase, to get the corresponding objects in each dynamically created ionic segments.
Floats is my array of objects. And based on the number of objects in the array I am able to add ion-segment dynamically, whereas switchcase fails.

.html

```
   <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment" color="primary" >
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let item of floats" [value]="item.id" (ionChange)="changeSegment()" >
              {{item.title}}
              </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <div class="panel-tab">
        <div [ngSwitch]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of floats; let x = index">
          <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'1'">{{item.title}} 
          <div>
              <div class="panel-cash">
                  <div class="panelcash-heading">Cash</div>
                  <div class="row header">  
                      <div class="col">Currency Type</div>
                      <div class="col">Sales</div>
                      <div class="col">Float</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item['cash']">
                        <div class="col">{{subitem.currency}}</div> 
                        <div class="col">{{subitem.sales}}</div>
                        <div class="col">{{subitem.float}}</div>
                  </div> 
              </div>

              <div class="panel-credit">
                  <div class="panelcredit-heading">Credit Card</div>
                  <div class="row header">    
                      <div class="col">Currency Type</div>
                      <div class="col">Sales</div>
                      <div class="col">Float</div> 
                  </div>

                  <div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item['credit']">
                      <div class="col">{{subitem.currency}}</div>
                      <div class="col">{{subitem.sales}}</div>
                      <div class="col">{{subitem.float}}</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </ion-list >
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could it be because your ids are stored as numbers and not strings? Your `ngSwitchCase` assumes strings.

Comment: i tried the same but still the error appear as "Can't bind to '*ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-list'"

Comment: Oh you didn't mention you got that error. In that case you'll have to put it on a native tag like a div, li, ul, etc. Ionic doesn't support it.

Comment: now i have overcome the error using *ngSwitchCase="item.id", by considering the id against ngSwitch. But the problem is ngSwitch is getting only the last id of object, hence only my last tab is getting data.